Kafka SASL_PLAINTEXT running in Docker container. Can't produce and consume messages
I am running Kafka in kRaft mode on Docker containers. I can produce and consume messages to brokers using command line but as soon as I try to do it using Python script from outside of the container I fail with the same error

%6|1715163671.929|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_plaintext://localhost:9094/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://localhost:9094/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 4ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)

Can anyone see any mistakes in configurations or any advice?
My docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:

kafka1:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
hostname: kafka1
container_name: kafka1
ports:
\- "9092:9092"
environment:
KAFKA_LISTENERS:INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092,
CONTROLLER://kafka1:29093
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,
EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:admin"
KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller,broker'
KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:29093,2@kafka2:29093,3@kafka3:29093'
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_SEGMENT_MS: 15000
KAFKA_METADATA_MAX_RETENTION_MS: 1200000
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_MAX_RECORD_BYTES_BETWEEN_SNAPSHOTS: 2800
KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
KAFKA_OPTS: '-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf'
CLUSTER_ID: '\<ClusterID\>'
volumes:
\- ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
\- kafka1-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
\- ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID

kafka2:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
hostname: kafka2
container_name: kafka2
ports:
\- "9093:9093"
environment:
KAFKA_LISTENERS:INTERNAL://kafka2:19093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093,
CONTROLLER://kafka2:29093
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:19093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,
EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:admin"
KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller,broker'
KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:29093,2@kafka2:29093,3@kafka3:29093'
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_SEGMENT_MS: 15000
KAFKA_METADATA_MAX_RETENTION_MS: 1200000
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_MAX_RECORD_BYTES_BETWEEN_SNAPSHOTS: 2800
KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
CLUSTER_ID: '\<ClusterID\>'
volumes:
\- ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
\- kafka2-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
\- ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID

kafka3:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
hostname: kafka3
container_name: kafka3
ports:
\- "9094:9094"
environment:
KAFKA_LISTENERS:INTERNAL://kafka3:19094,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094,
CONTROLLER://kafka3:29093
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:19094,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,
INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: "User:admin"
KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller,broker'
KAFKA_NODE_ID: 3
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:29093,2@kafka2:29093,3@kafka3:29093'
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_SEGMENT_MS: 15000
KAFKA_METADATA_MAX_RETENTION_MS: 1200000
KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_MAX_RECORD_BYTES_BETWEEN_SNAPSHOTS: 2800
KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
CLUSTER_ID: '\<CLusterID\>'
volumes:
\- ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
\- kafka3-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
\- ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID

volumes:
kafka1-data:
kafka2-data:
kafka3-data:

My kafka_server_jaas.conf
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="secret-admin"
user_usera="secret-usera";

};

My Python script
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def delivery_report(err, msg):
"""Delivery report callback."""
if err is not None:
print(f'Message delivery failed: {err}')
else:
print(f'Message delivered to {msg.topic()} \[{msg.partition()}\]')

def main():
conf = {
'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094',
'security.protocol': 'sasl_plaintext',
'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
'sasl.username': 'usera',
'sasl.password': 'secret-users',
}

    producer = Producer(conf)
    
    # Produce a test message to check the connection
    try:
        producer.produce('test_topic', key='test_key', value='test_value',
        callback=delivery_report)
        producer.flush()  # Wait for message delivery
        print("Message sent successfully. Connection to Kafka is working.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    
    # Close the producer
    producer.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()


KAFKA_LISTENERS should include 0.0.0.0 rather than localhost to listen externally to the Docker network. Might not fix the error, but it's one issue. You also shouldn't use /tmp for the log dirs since that's not the volume you're mounting

Also, typo? I see secret-users in the code, but not the JAAS file

Thanks! Yeah. Just a typo :) Result is the same.
